# Why does the max function aggregate?

Tags: business-objects, webi

I want to return the maximum value in a column in a block with values for 13 periods.

`Max([CountVariable])` returns the value against each period.

`Max([CountVariable] forAll([Period))` returns the sum of all values.

This is what I am getting:

```
Period CountVariable Max([CountVariable])  Max([CountVariable] forAll([Period))
1      10            10                    45
2      15            15                    45
3      20            20                    45
```

This is what I'd like:

```
Period CountVariable Max
1      10            20
2      15            20
3      20            20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  To get the maximum for all periods, you need to set the variable to evaluate in the **output context**.  You do this by specifying the context operator (ForAll) outside of the Max() function.  So:

```
Max([CountVariable]) forAll([Period])
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the reply but that's still not working. I understand what you mean and expected it to but it's still just returned the same. The countvariable is actually the period - which is a dimension. Should that matter? Behaviour is same regardless - if I use max of a count or max of period..

Comment: ignore that - I had another dimension in the block! when I added that to forall, it worked. thanks a bunch.